# He took the fun/zing/excitement out of it?

Tags: word-choice

I have a expression like this:

> He was supposed to tell us about his experiences of his recent trip and we all were looking forward to it but he took the **fun/zing/excitement/anything else** out of it as he skipped the LA, Vegas part.

I know they are correct but which one of these is most common/appropriate or in other words  most instinctive one.

Answer (score 3):

"Zing" is appropriate if you want an intentionally strong sense of informality. "Took the fun out of it" conveys a sense of reproach and suggests actively damping spirits rather than just defaulting. If you want to express disappointment without reproach and don't want to be too informal, "excitement" would be the best choice.

Even that conveys a certain amount of reproach, and you might prefer to say "it took the excitement out of it when he ..." rather than that he took the excitement out.